# Get the active menu parent from a menu block

Tags: blocks

I'm attempting to use `hook_block_view_alter()` to set a block title to the name of the page's parent menu item.

The block is a menu block for the main menu that is showing second-level items.

I've found that this works to set the title:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_alter().
 */
function nama_components_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  if ($build['#id'] == 'nama_d8_main_menu') {
    $parent_menu_item = 'just testing!';
    $build['#configuration']['label'] = $parent_menu_item;
    $build['#configuration']['label_display'] = 1;
  }
}
```

From here, how would I look up the parent menu item from the block so I can actually set `$parent_menu_item`? I've looked through what I'm getting in the `$build` and `$block` parameters, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @ScottAnderson Ugh, no, I ended up kinda faking it with JavaScript on that project. I suppose it did solve the problem in that case, but there's got to be a better way. I ended up with [this JS](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d82717f722e8dc0bebc54fb6b4c7104e) in a module (included via a moduleName.libraries.yml file). You'd of course need to adjust the selectors shown there. Hope you find a better solution!